# How to change the label for username to 'username/email' in login page in Django

Tags: django

I am building a car rental website with Django. Currently working on user authentication.The user can either use his/her username/email and password to login.It's working fine. My question is, how will I change the label for username field to "username/email" so that the user can understand that either username or email can be entered. I cannot  make changes in the login.html template because I have used there {{ form.as_p }} tag and the concerned portion in my forms.py file has:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

I am not able to understand where to make changes. Please help.

Comment: form.as_p has very predictable behavior. Why not just recreate what it would look like with raw html and set the fields to whatever labels you want and not use as_p? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

Comment: Yes done it with label and input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom label for form field like this

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username/email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```